# Show / hide courses based on user role on Moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm running a Moodle site where I have two roles, "Role A" and "Role B". I have few courses on my site and I want to restrict some courses to be visible only to users with the role "Role A" and some courses to be visible only to users with the role "Role B".

Courses which are visible to users with "Role A" should not be enrolled / accessed by the users with "Role B" and vice-versa.

Is there any Moodle permission to set course accessibility based on roles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, by an administrator in Administration > Site administration > Users > Permissions > User policies.

For reference  https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/User_policies

Comment: I want to define which role should be able to access a course and which role should not.